# Why isn't my image scaling correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-canvas

I'm trying to have an image scale to a certain size depending on the horizontal size sent to an update function, but the following code doesnt seem to size the image correctly.

EDIT: The code:

```
public class GlassesView extends View {

    private Paint paint;
    private BitmapFactory.Options options;
    private Bitmap bitmapOrg;
    private Bitmap target;
    private Bitmap bitmapRev;
    private Bitmap resizedBitmap;

    private int currY;

    public int glassesX;
    public int glassesY;
    public float glassesSizeX;
    public float glassesSizeY;
    private boolean drawGlasses;
    private boolean glassesMirrored;

    public GlassesView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setDither(false);
        paint.setAntiAlias(false);

        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inScaled = false;

        bitmapOrg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.micro_glasses, options), 32, 5, false);
        bitmapRev = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.glasses_reverse, options), 32, 5, false);
        drawGlasses = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(target, 0, 0, paint);

        boolean moving = currY < glassesY;
        if (moving) {
            currY++;
        }
        if (drawGlasses) {
            int newWidth = resizedBitmap.getWidth();
            int newHeight = resizedBitmap.getHeight();
            Paint bluey = new Paint();
            bluey.setColor(Color.argb(64, 0, 0, 255));
            canvas.drawRect(new Rect(glassesX, currY, glassesX + newWidth,
                    currY + newHeight), bluey);

            canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, glassesX, currY, paint);
        }
        if (moving) {
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void drawGlasses(int x1, int x2, int y, boolean mirror) {
        drawGlasses = true;
        glassesMirrored = mirror;
        if (!mirror) {
            glassesSizeX = (float) (x2 - x1) / (float) (25 - 16);
            glassesSizeY = glassesSizeX;
            glassesY = y - (int)(1*glassesSizeX);
            glassesX = (int) (x1 - (glassesSizeX * 16));
        } else {
            glassesSizeX = (float) (x1 - x2) / (float) (25 - 16);
            glassesSizeY = glassesSizeX;
            glassesY = y - (int)(1*glassesSizeX);
            glassesX = (int) (x1 - (glassesSizeX * 16));
        }

        currY = -1;

        if (!glassesMirrored) {
            resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg,
                    (int) (bitmapOrg.getWidth() * glassesSizeX),
                    (int) (bitmapOrg.getHeight() * glassesSizeY), false);
        } else {
            resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapRev,
                    (int) (bitmapRev.getWidth() * glassesSizeX),
                    (int) (bitmapRev.getHeight() * glassesSizeY), false);
        }
    }

    public void setTargetPic(Bitmap targetPic) {
        target = targetPic;
    }

}
```

[The result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttK7a.png) (The blue rectangle being the bounding box of the image's intended size)

Which part am I going wrong at?

EDIT 2:
Here are the glasses: [image: glasses]

EDIT 3:
Out of curiousity, I ran it on my actual phone, and got a [much different result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdX5x.png), the image was stretched passed the intended blue box.

EDIT 4:
I tried running the app on a few emulators to see if it was an Android version incompatibility thing, but they all seemed to work perfectly. The scaling issue only occurs on my phone (Vibrant, rooted, CM7) and my cousin's (Droid, also rooted). These are the only physical devices I have tested on, but they both seem to have the same issue.
I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out here, this is a huge roadblock in my project and no other forums or message groups are responding.

EDIT 5:
I should mention that in update 4, the code changed a bit, which fixed the problem in the emulators as I stated, but doesn't work on physical devices. Changes are updated in the code above. **desperate for help** :P

EDIT 6:
Yet another update, I tested the same code on my old G1, and it works perfectly as expected. I have absolutely no clue now.

Comment: I assumed it would be too long, no?

Comment: You are allowed/encouraged to post code directly in your question.  If it is too long, it will automatically be set to scroll (if you format it properly!)  That said, I don't think putting your code elsewhere was worth a down-vote.

Comment: Ah thank you, I wasn't aware it would scroll for me; I apologize for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what was wrong. The image has to be in a folder called "drawable-nodpi", otherwise it will be scaled depending on DPI.

Answer (score 1):

have you been using the /res/drawable-nodpi/ directory to store your images?

Apparently if you use the /drawable-ldpi/, /drawable-mdpi/ or /drawable-hdpi/ folders, Android will apply scaling to the image when you load it depending on the device. The reason your G1 may work is that it may not require any scaling depending on the folder you used.

Also, your IMGUR links are broken... also your code doesn't seem correct... you call DrawGlasses with no arguments.

Comment: Thank you this works! Yeah the links expired, and I didn't call the method in this java file so I'm not sure what you're referring to about me calling it with no arguments.

Regardless, thank you again!

Comment: Oh I see... you have a method called drawGlasses and a private member as well... probably not the best practice as it's confusing when looking over the code to have a variable/function of the same name in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, glassesWidth,   
                                           glassesHeight, matrix, false);
```

Change the last parameter from false to true.
you can have a try.

The follow is i used zoom in method by scale:

```
 private void small()    {  
     int bmpWidth=bmp.getWidth();   
     int bmpHeight=bmp.getHeight();  

     Log.i(TAG, "bmpWidth = " + bmpWidth + ", bmpHeight = " + bmpHeight);  

     /* 设置图片缩小的比例 */  
     double scale=0.8;  
     /* 计算出这次要缩小的比例 */   
     scaleWidth=(float) (scaleWidth*scale);   
     scaleHeight=(float) (scaleHeight*scale);   
     /* 产生reSize后的Bitmap对象 */  
     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();  
     matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);  
     Bitmap resizeBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp,0,0,bmpWidth,   
             bmpHeight,matrix,true);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, all that change did was anti-alias and dither my image (which I'm trying to avoid, as the glasses are supposed to be pixelated). The glasses stayed the same size though.

Comment: I also know that the resized bitmap object is the correct size, since in my code I use its dimensions to create the blue rectangle.